# SMS hyperlink showing multiple images issue

Tags: hyperlink, sms, facebook-opengraph, meta

When I send a hyperlink url via sms (iphone 10) the og meta image comes out as a 3 image collage. However it works fine when I send the same hyperlink in social platforms like FB, Instagram...etc. FB debugger shows the picture as normal...

Please view attached pics.

anyone?

[image]

Comment: Your page currently provides three links to Open Graph images (which is fine per the standard). I shared a link to your site via WhatsApp on Android (I don’t have an iPhone) and it shows one image, not three. As an experiment, what happens with iMessage if you temporarily remove the 2nd and 3rd image references?

Comment: The issue seems to have disappeared: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65371991/opengraph-image-standards-for-facebook-whatsapp-and-imessage/65827567#65827567